# gnome terminal: Directory not found (running python script in another terminal)

Tags: terminal, gnome

I was creating a python script for Kali Linux to execute some commands using os module.
Now I want to run another script using the following script using gnome-terminal, using the  following code:

.

.

.

os.system("gnome-terminal -e ./home/kali/Desktop/folder/secondphase.py")

.

.

But on execution, in new terminal, it give error "No such directory found". I've checked that the path to secondphase.py script is correct, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have put .(dot) in the beginning of root directory,
This should work.

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e /home/kali/Desktop/folder/secondphase.py")
```